# How to emit newer class file versions with Scala (50.0/51.0)?

Tags: java, class, scala, versioning, bytecode

I want to test the new type-checking bytecode verifier with classes created by `scalac`.

`scalac` currently outputs version 49.0 class files, but the new type-checking verifier is only mandatory since version 51.0.

I tried to "preverify" the classes with ProGuard (which in fact converted them to version 50.0), but I' not sure if the new verifier just fell back to the old type-inferencing verifier automatically.

How can I convert class files to version 51.0 (or how can I find out which verifier is used when loading version 50.0 class files)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like FJBG (the library NSC uses to generate bytecode) has seen *some* effort at supporting [StackMap](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/fjbg/ch/epfl/lamp/fjbg/JStackMapTableAttribute.java) but I have no idea how far along it is.

If you ask on scala-internals, Stephane Michelou might pop up.  He's the guy who's been [working on it](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/23854).

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was quite interesting and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think that bytecode format has not been ever changed deeply and that it is probably always backward compatible. (If you know something about bytecode, remember longs and doubles on constant pool and operand stack, which were designed a bit crazily. It hasn't been modified, has it?) So, changing major/minor number will probably work.

How to do it? There are two ways:

- Use hexa editor and modify it manually. It should be really simple if you know the position of the bytes. There it the [bytecode specification][1], which says, that you should skip the first four bytes and you will see two bytes of minor version and two bytes of major version (in this order).
- Use an library. I've some experience with BCEL. It does not seem to be the best designed library which I've ever seen, but it should be good enough for your case. I've seen methods setMinor and setMajor in a class (look at ClassGen and the "almost-immutable" JavaClass).

[1] http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html

Comment: No, this won't work. 51.0 introduces a mandatory StackMap attribute, which is used with the type-checking verifier. Changing the version won't add it.

Comment: Hmm, that is interresting. I've thought that it is not mandatory. (I'm not talking about a similar concept in J2ME.) However, I don't understand the "preverify" action you did. If it was the J2ME preverify, it would not IMHO convert the classfile to such new version. If it would be the newer concept, it would have to convert it to 51.0 and not 50.0. By the way, you can also check ASM library/tools. I've used it for some bytecode verifications while debugging and it was able to infer operand stack types, so generating StackMap can be built on this IMHO simply.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) to parse the bytecode.  I know that scala (and clojure) use ASM internally, so the effort spent to learn it won't be wasted.  You can probably throw together a [ClassReader](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html) and an [EmptyVisitor](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/EmptyVisitor.html) that overrides the visit method that provides header information fairly quickly.

Comment: scala does not use ASM internally.

Comment: I had even thought check it online before I said it.  Apparently only the scala [eclipse plugin](https://codereview.scala-lang.org/fisheye/qsearch?q=org.objectweb.asm).  My appologies for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I know it may be obvious, but I'm not sure after reading your question so I'll ask:

Are you using a beta build? Like in one of the nightly builds? Or do you want to modify the current release?

EDIT: Ok, there is something I don't get here. I've just tried the nightly builds and yes, they are version 49.0. But as far as I know this is set by the compiler.

You are trying to change the version to get access to some new fancy functionality. But that doesn't make sense to me. If the compiler releases version 49.0, you changing it to any newer version (50.0, 51.0 or 70.0 for what matters) should not have any impact. As far as I know the version is to ensure compatibility, which means that you won't run a newer class with an older VM that won't support your language.

So, in you case, adding a new version will mean that, probably, the current VM won't want to run your code. And even if it does, it probably doesn't contain the functionality you mention, if that functionality is only in version 51.0 which your current compiler/VM doesn't support.

I mean, maybe what you are trying to do is completely normal and it's simply that I don't know about it and I'm showing my ignorance in this area :) , but I think there something missing there.

Comment: I'm using the current 2.9 trunk.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one of the easiest things to do would be to use a java decompiler (see [JADClipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/) for an Eclipse plugin) and then recompile the source to whatever version you need.

Comment: I don't think it will survive the roundtrip between Scala source -> bytecode -> Java source -> bytecode. Not everything in Scala can be translated to Java.